Is it possible to create an Eevee material that changes its color depending on if a specific object is behind it?
I want to make an outline that is made with a solidify modifier with inverted normals with backface-culling, where the color of the outline is controlled with a texture. There are however scenarios where the color shouldn't be based on a texture, but rather a pre-specified color in the material. This color should be used when parts of the outline are rendered on top of the object that it is acting as an outline for (or with an alternative description: if that part of the outline is overlapping with the silhouette of the object that it is acting as an outline for). I want the outline material to act like this since I will make the outline color be quite similar to the base model's colors. If the outline is around the silhouette of the model than the outline will be pretty visible however if the outline is rendered on top of the model itself, like when looking at a concave model from certain angles, then I feel like it could be hard to see the outline due to the similar colors, where I would instead want to "overwrite" that part of the outline with some other color, like pure black for example.
Is this something that is possible to do with a material? I know that it is most likely possible in the compositor, but if possible I would like to avoid that since I feel like it could be very messy and confusing having to think about all of the different render layers when rendering scenes that contain stuff behind and in front of the model with the outline.
